# Penn tree Bank tagset for NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I am using NLTK as a part of my project, and have implemented Viterbi algorithm for the purpose of tagging (although I am aware of the fact that a tagger is very much available).
I have used the following snipped in my code

```
tagdict = load('help/tagsets/brown_tagset.pickle')
taglist = tagdict.keys()
tag_sequence_corpus = brown.tagged_sents(tagset='brown')
```

The first two lines have been used to extract the keys out of the brown tag-set, where the keys are the list of tags available in the Brown tag-set.
The argument tag-set='brown' in third line is used to tag the brown corpus according to the tag-set offered by the Brown corpus.

Is there any means by which I can set the tag-set argument to the Penn bank tag-set? The motivation for pursuing so is the fact that the Penn Bank tree has some 36-45 tags, which makes it feasible to implement the Viterbi algorithm (complexity of the algorithms being O(n*|S|^3) ) where n is the length of the sentence ans |S| refers to the magnitude of the tag-set, while the brown corpus has some ~226 tags in it (which increases the computation time). And the universal tag-set is prone to word sense ambiguity.

If PTB tagger is not available, may anyone suggest an alternative to it (apart from Brown/universal)?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last sentence in your question indicates that you're aware of the `universal` tagset: It only has about 10 POS tags, because they need to be broad enough for other tagsets to be mapped *to* them. The Penn Treebank tagset has a many-to-many relationship to Brown, so no (reliable) automatic mapping is possible.

What you can do is use one of the corpora that are already tagged with the Penn Treebank tagset. The NLTK's sample of the `treebank` corpus is only 1/10th the size of Brown (100,000 words), but it might be enough for your purposes.

Alternately, you can simplify the Brown corpus yourself: If you only keep the first part of compound tags like `VBN-TL-HL` or `PPS+HVD`, the 472 complex tags are reduced to 71. If that's still too many, inspect the definitions and manually collapse it further, e.g. by merging `NN` and `NNS` (singular and plural).